# Чи можна вживати слово "придбані" замість "здобуті" у контексті з "злочинним шляхом"

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами

Знайшов у статті наступне: "Поліція знайшла людей, які викрали троянди. Придбані злочинним шляхом квіти, ця пара привезла на власне подвір’я, та посадила у дворі."

Підскажіть, будь ласка, чи можна вживати слово "придбані" у цьому контексті?

Answer (score 3):

Мені здається, це не помилка. Фактично вся множина значень слова *[придбавати](http://sum.in.ua/s/prydbavaty)* зводиться до того, що своїми зусиллям суб'єкт тепер має щось, чого раніше не мав (наприклад, «став власником чого-небудь; набув/нажив», іноді «завів» абощо):

> А ти, Латине, всіх благійший, придбав Енею дар смачнійший: йому Лавинію оддай. // Іван Котляревський, «Енеїда», 1827.
>
> Сопить наш хорунженко і нічого йому не сказав, тільки гукнув у кімнату: «Ану, сестро! дай нам поснідати, що ти там придбала». // Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, «Конотопська відьма», 1833.
>
> Цвіркунка: Дай же, боже, сестро, вам дочку віддати, зятя придбати й онуків діждати. // Яков Кухаренко, «Чорноморський побит», 1836.
>
> Добро його, **придбане неправдою**, щезне, яко воск од лиця огня, перейде ік чужим людям, і рід його нанівеч зведеться. // Митрофан Александрович, «Антін Михайлович Танський», 1861 (ред. Ю. Винничук, 1990).
>
> Характерну річ почув сьогодні: Київський голова Толлі (з греків) **всякими неправдами придбав** собі за 200 чи 300 т[исяч] історичне, добре відоме містечко Вишневець, що коштує певних 2 мільйони. // Олександр Кониський, «Думки і помітки», 1885.
>
> Наші суперечники можуть відповісти нам, що хоч справді контракт був повернений у нівець насиллям, облудою й підступом одного з контрагентів, але другий контрагент вже згубив не тільки право розпоряджатися своєю долею, але навіть право протестування, бо своїм довговіковим мовчанням він освятив неправні вчинки, і те, що було **придбане кривдою**, на підставі задавнення зробилось правним. // Микола Міхновський, «Самостійна Україна», 1900.
>
> Я її не вкрав і не **придбав оманою**. // Ольга Кобилянська, «Земля», 1901.
>
> Бо вони їдять хлїб беззаконностї, а вино попивають (з добра), що **насильством придбали**. // Біблія (пер. Пантелеймон Куліш, Іван Пулюй, Іван Нечуй-Левицький, 1904).
>
> — Еге-ге, ваша правда: воно, хазяйствечко, любить ока, гулянки його не прибільшують. А тимчасом і люди (є у нас такі!) — той курку, той овечку, той поросятко, воно, мовляв, **неправдою надбане**, не гріх його й узяти, гляди й звели! — додала Килина, вернувшись з водою з яру. // Дніпрова Чайка, «Вона його любила», 1909–1919.
>
> І там знайшлися б місіонери з **шахрайськи придбаними** ланами, копальні з акціями, плянтації, мандарин з повинністю, — всі, всі вони заявили б претенсію на нього. // Олесь Досвітній, «Американці», 1919.

(Також [пошук у «ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=([lemma%3D"(%D0%BD%D0%B0|%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8)%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F(%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)"]+[tag%3D".*oru.*"+%26+word!%3D"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"])+|+([tag%3D".*oru.*"+%26+word!%3D"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"]+[lemma%3D"(%D0%BD%D0%B0|%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8)%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F(%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)"])+|+([lemma%3D"(%D0%BD%D0%B0|%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8)%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F(%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)"]+"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"+[tag%3D".*oru.*"+%26+word!%3D"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"])+|+([tag%3D".*oru.*"+%26+word!%3D"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"]+"%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE|%D1%97%D1%97"+[lemma%3D"(%D0%BD%D0%B0|%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8)%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F(%D1%82%D0%B8|%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)"])) знаходить «придбано нечесним шляхом», «придбав тишком більше половини акцій», «придбав її хапливою рукою, а не серцем щедрим, правдою та гідністю» тощо.)

У Вашому прикладі *придбавати*, мені здається, можна інтерпретувати як «набувати/наживати»: «Набуті злочинним шляхом квіти…». Також доволі схожу множину значень має слово *[надбавати](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=54100&page=1722)*.

Але оскільки на практиці зараз *придбавати* означає найчастіше саме «купувати» (тобто потрібне нам значення входить у повну множину значень слова *придбавати*, але не входить у найуживанішу зараз підмножину), то таке вживання, як у Вашому прикладі, справді може видаватися дивним.

Answer (score 2):

Звісно, що ні. Де ж там "дбати", коли крадеш? Дбати — це семантика, яка аж сочиться зі слова "придбати".

Придбати — це здобути дбайливим шляхом.

Знаю, що тут без словників не люблять відповіді. Тримайте гарних скріншотів з [етимологічного словника](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm):

[image: слово дбати етимологія]

[image: слово дбати етимологія]

[image: слово дбати етимологія]

Придбати, надбати — **нажити**, заробити, аж ніяк не вкрасти.

Хоча в вашій цитаті автор може відчув пересадку вкрадених трояндів як дбайливість. У такому разі варіянти два: або автор вміє в іронію як Котляревський у прикладах з іншої відповіді, або не тямить нашої мови.

Взагалі *"здобутий злочинним шляхом"* — це така жаска канцелярщина, що я вже покинув ждати, коли наші журналісти навчаться писати по-людськи.

Comment: Спочатку хотів на 100% погодитися, аргумент про те, що має бути семантичний зв'язок із _дбати_, звучить переконливо. Але потім помітив, що за Вашим же посиланням первісне значення _*dъbati_ — це лише «шукати, здобути» (а не таке, як у сучасного _дбати_); і не виключено, що в деяких словах з префіксами збереглися відтінки саме старих значень. Тож особисто для мене питання поки лишається відкритим.

Comment: Я додав приклади а-ля «насильством придбали» у свою [відповідь](/a/6221).

Comment: Пане @Sasha, все-таки українська і праслов'янська мови — це різні мови. :) Придбати насильством — це те саме, що вилікувати вбивством. Для гуморески або метафори як у Біблії Куліша згодиться. Всі додані вами приклади з художньої літератури, а там, знаєте, гратися словами — не схотінка, а обов'язок. Це ж не Вікіпедія.

Comment: Українська походить з праслов'янської. Якщо у певних випадках значення кореня змінилося, це ще не означає, що воно в усіх випадках змінилося. Я сумніваюся, що це все гуморески/метафори, але може, Ви й маєте рацію.

Comment: Добре, художня література Вас не переконує. А що Вас переконає? Публіцистика?

Comment: @Sasha А в публіцистиці не може бути гумору й гри словами? Що за нудну публіцистику ви читаєте. :)